# How to maintain city road data? (What data structure should I use)

Tags: c++, data-structures, geometry

(Sorry my English is not good, but I will try to phrase it clearly)

For example, I've got road data in a form like this:

```
          Latitude      Longitude
RoadA(consists of 2 dots)
          31.263319     121.5555711
          31.2619722    121.5564754
RoadB(consists of 3 dots)
          31.2619722    121.5564754
          31.2611567    121.557023
          31.2610903    121.557088
```

As you can see, each road consists of several (2~x) dots. The road may be a curve and need many dots to describe it. Between two dots they are connected by a  straight line.

Once I have read in all the road data, I will read in a set of dots, my task here is that once a new dot is given, I need to find out if it is on any of the roads. If not, I need to draw a perpendicular towards the nearest road and find out the coordinate of the pedal foot(the nearest point on road).

The amount of query is huge, so I need the speed to be as fast as possible.What kind of data structure should I use?

Comment: Use an open source database like sqlite3. Your data headers will become the database fields.

Comment: You just need to explain/retranslate the word "pedal foot".

Comment: I think it means the nearest point on road

Comment: yes , i mean the nearest point on road

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24461631/5980430) may be related

Comment: maybe [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/23493) can help, too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some Spatial Partitioning methods in Game Development and theory.
Maybe you should use one of them.
[link](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/spatial-partition.html)

You should partition your locations in Binary,Quad,Oct, ... trees.
I think the best way, is to use a map of Pairs.

Comment: I think the best way to find the nearest point is spatial partitioning. spatial partitioning is used in game development. Why downvote?